# OpenGL multiple contexts issue in multi-threaded Java app

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, lwjgl

I thought it would be simple to setup:I have 2 threads,each one contains completely separated OpenGL application which acquires its context from its own PBuffer.So the idea is to render in  2 different context in parallel.What happens is that the first thread renders ok but the second one fails.I wonder if it's possible at all doing a parallel rendering using separate contexts? 
I am using Java [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) wrapper for OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.I forgot to remove some static objects which I think couldn't be used by both threads at the time.Now it works.